# Simple swing application. The jar file runs on my computer, but not others

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, manifest

This is my first question, so apologies for any mistakes. I'll try and give all the info I can. Basically I've written a simple swing application which just loads in image into a JPanel and displays it. I'm using Netbeans 7.1 and I have the latest version of the Java SDK. 
Anyway, I've used the "Build" feature in NetBeans 7.1 to deploy my application into a Jar file. When I double click the Jar File on my PC, it runs without a problem. However when I put it on other computers (Tested on 2 others so far, both with the most current JRE) it fails to open, citing the following error:

> could not find the main class: swong.Startup. Program will exit

swong is my package name, and Startup is the location of my main method. I have checked the manifest file which is created with Netbeans' build, and it[the manifest] does indeed contain the location of my main method class.

From searching, I've come across similar issues in which the classpath is set wrongly, but I don't understand how this could cause my particular error.

If someone could help me, I would be over the moon. I've been studying java for a year or so, and I've got a good handle down, but I've NEVER been able to make a Jar that runs on a computer which wasn't my own. So, 10 points and thanks in advance.

xo.

EDIT: Thank you for the responses. I'm doing shift work and swamped, but I will test and poke with these responses tomorrow and provide more information. Thanks again. xo

Comment: if you run from command prompt via java -jar yourJarFile.jar what error it gives on non working machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had d same problem while distributing my app. There is 1 solution that you create a batch file with 'java -jar AppName.jar' and asking user to double click on this batch file to execute your app. What i did was to provide a JRE installation exe(eg: jre_1.7.0) with your app.
Now create a Batch file (install.bat) in which write following commands

jre_1.7.0   -> this will install jre on user's pc

set path="C\Program Files\Java\jre_1.7.0\bin"

java -jar yourAppName.jar

Why i installed JRE because different people have different JRE versions installed. So this makes it difficult to set path to the installed JRE's bin folder & calling the 'java -jar' command. Hence as you know which folders your JRE installation will create hence it is easy to set path and execute your jar file with 'java-jar' command.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your jar file has the following structure (at least)

```
jarfile.jar
  |---------- swong
                |---------- Startup.class
  |---------- META-INF
                |---------- MANIFEST.MF
```

It seems like the class "Startup" is missing. Maybe your jar only contains the .java files, not the compiled classes.

Answer (score 0):

This error message can be a mistakable java7 error, when you try to start java7 compiled classes with a different Java Runtime Environment then java7. Have you validated, that your .jar is started within a Java7 environment on those other test machines? Sometimes it happens, that you have installed different versions of JREs and you might not be sure which one is actually started.

To check which enviroment is used, you can check in your registry for the following value:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command

this should point to your latest JRE. Or if you'd like to stay compatible to java6 as well, define the appropiate compile level in your build environment.